# jquery ajax post - how to get data back?

Tags: php, jquery

I have a profile page that contains a series of images. I want to use jQuery to allow the user to delete an image from the server and have the page update without reloading the entire page. When it's successful, it will remove the image's containing div from the page. My delete function is PHP; fairly simple:

*delete.php*

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['id'])) {     
    if (unlink($_POST['id'])) { 
        echo "success";
    } 
    else { 
        echo "failure"; 
    } 
} 
?>
```

(There's already user authentication in place just to get them to the page that calls delete.php.)

Here's the html of one displayed image - there can be up to 5 of these chunks one after another:

```
<div class="box">
  <img src="uploads/t_10DOT_22C_1111_1300370702_3.jpg" /> 
  <h5><a rel="external" href="uploads/10DOT_22C_1111_1300370702_3.jpg">See full version</a></h5> 
  <a href="#" id="10DOT_22C_1111_1300370702_3.jpg" class="delete" onclick="return ConfirmDelete();" >x</a>
  <div class="clear"></div> 
</div>
```

My jQuery so far looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#load').hide();
});

$(function() {
$(".delete").click(function() {
$('#load').fadeIn();
var commentContainer = $(this).parent();
var id = $(this).attr("id");
var string = 'id='+ id ;

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "delete.php",
   data: string,
   cache: false,
   success: function(data){
    commentContainer.slideUp('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});
    $('#load').fadeOut();
  }

 });

return false;
    });
});
```

The part I'm concerned with is the ajax post. How does the success part actually work? What do I need to do in my php file so that ajax knows whether the delete was a success or failure?

Comment: don't forget to actually validate the supplied post ID.  Otherwise I could potentially send 'id=delete.php' and remove your file!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once an ajax post request has finished executing the file you sent the request to, if there was no error, the code you add in the "success" section is executed, in this case

```
success: function(data){
  /*The code you need*/
});
```

The previous part if where the code is executed, the "data" variable contains anything you return from your php file, it can be data, it can be a simple "true" or "false", you choose what to send to let your jQuery know if it was successful.

Hope this helps a bit.

Edit Note:

```
function(applyData){
  if ( applyData.toString() == 'invalid' ){
    $('#pollError').html('Global styles cannot be modified.');
    $('#pollNotice').html('');
  }
  else{
    $('#pollNotice').html('The changes to the style have been applied.');
  }
});
```

The previous example is a live example of what you can do inside the function in the "success" event. There I handle an "invalid" status and otherwise it's successful, after that I refresh a couple DIVs in case of invalid or update a single DIV in case of success.

This is the php that executes:

```
if ( !$db->isGlobal($id_css)){
  $data['id_poll'] = $id_poll;
  $data['id_css'] = $id_css;
  $data['css'] = $css;
  $db->applyCssChanges($data);
}
else{
  echo 'invalid';
}
```

Comment: So if I change my PHP to say if (unlink($_POST['id'])) { 
        return true;
    } the success function will run. What if PHP returns false (i.e. in an else statement, where the delete did not complete)?

Comment: The success function will run no matter what you send, just to clarify, the only way the success function won't run is when there's an error running the php file. If your file returns something, whether it's a "true", a "false" or even an array, the function will run. Finally, when the function runs, the "data" variable will contain everything you sent back.

Comment: So what happens if there's an error when the PHP runs? How can I handle that via jquery? I don't want to just echo out the error from the delete.php, since that file doesn't contain any of the site navigation. I'd like to display an error message in the same div I'd display a success message.

Comment: I added a live example in my answer to show you a way to handle the results coming from the php file :)

Comment: Thanks. I'm very new to jQuery and wasn't sure if I could put an if/else block inside the success function.

Comment: You can put almost anything inside it :) I'm glad my answer helped :)

Answer (score 1):

You've two obvious options I can think of:

1. Your returned text should appear in the `data` parameter supplied to your `success` callback function - however you'll probably also need to make sure it's in a format compatible with the MIME `Content-Type` returned by your PHP, or jQuery might complain that it can't parse it, or:
2. Send back a [`5xx Failure`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error) type message from your PHP using the `header()` function if the delete didn't work.  That should then trigger an AJAX `error` callback, which you'll need to supply.

Comment: But HOW does my returned text end up in the data parameter supplied to success? Everything I've seen says that data is actually the param you're passing INTO the post function, not what you're getting back.

Comment: there's two `data`s in your code - the one that's a key in the object you're supplying in the call to `$.ajax`, and the one that's a parameter to the success function.  _That_ one will contain the response text.  To avoid confusion, rename it.

Comment: Thanks. The examples I've seen all use 'data' in both places, so I assumed it was the same variable. Naming them differently makes it much clearer to me.

Answer (score 0):

From delete.php return whether the delete succeeded or not. In the success even check for that data and handle it appropriately.

HTH.

Comment: Not helpful; the entire question was HOW do I check for the data returned by PHP?